# How to arrange all audio buttons in the sequential order by using CSS and HTML?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am developing one page by using HTML, CSS and JavaScript, in that one div class is there which contains three icon buttons , now what i want is those three icons or buttons in a same line one is at left side ,next one is at middle and remaining one is the last of the page , How to achieve this thing please help me...

Answer (score 1):

Use `justify-content: space-between;`.

Snippet:

```css
.audio-sections {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="audio-sections">

  <audio autoplay id="player1">
    <source src=" https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=12HimBI_MQcCDx9chQsl05XCEGrfrFnEO" type="audio/mpeg">
  </audio>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ka-f.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/css/free.min.css?" />
    <button id="music1" onclick="document.getElementById('player1').play();">
      <i class="fa fa-headphones" id="pods" style='font-size:24px;' aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </button>
   


    <audio  autoplay id="player2">
          <source src="https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=11wfYWiukbIZJQnDL385jQs2SGQA5ESbL" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ka-f.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/css/free.min.css?" />
      <button id="music" onclick="document.getElementById('player2').play()">
        <i style='font-size:24px;' class='fas'>&#xf7a6;</i>
      </button>


    <audio  autoplay id="player3">
          <source src="https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=11wfYWiukbIZJQnDL385jQs2SGQA5ESbL" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ka-f.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/css/free.min.css?" />
      <button id="music" onclick="document.getElementById('player3').play()">
        <i style='font-size:24px;' class='fas'>&#xf7a6;</i>
      </button>
</div>
```

You can read more on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content)

Comment: it's not working for me, i paste my entire code in question section, once please check

Comment: it's working better than pasting the entire code you must understand it, you have to add CSS to make it work.

Comment: @saitarun you got on your css `button {position: absolute;}`...

Comment: what i have to change i have to remove this position:absolute na

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't understand what the final wanted design. As for your question - you can't expect element that have absolute position to obey flexbox parent.... If you remove this rule (ie `button{position:absolute}`) and add `.audio-sections {display: flex; justify-content: space-between;} ` it will put those 3 button as you want.